# Mysql WEEKDAY() vs Mysql DayofWeek()

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to understand the both but I am getting really confused. Online it says:

MySQL **WEEKDAY()** returns the index of the day in a week for a given date (0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday and ......6 for Sunday). MySQL **DAYOFWEEK()** returns the week day number (1 for Sunday,2 for Monday …… 7 for Saturday ) for a date specified as argument.

Can anyone explain with an example for both? Thank you.

Comment: `select weekday(now()), dayofweek(now())` - there’s your “example”. And if you still have trouble understanding anything in particular about this - then start by describing what that is. Please go read [ask].

Comment: `DAYOFWEEK` uses the ODBC standard while `WEEKDAY` does not.  Other than this, the documentation reveals no difference that I can see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A relevant difference is that weekday counts the days of the week from Monday, as follows and start from 0

0=Monday, 1=Tuesday, 2=Wednesday, 3=Thursday, 4=Friday, 5=Saturday, 6=Sunday

On the other hand dayofweek counts the days of the week from Sunday and start with 1

1=Sunday, 2=Monday, 3=Tuesday, 4=Wednesday, 5=Thursday, 6=Friday, 7=Saturday

Please try

select weekday(now()) weekday, dayofweek(now()) dayofweek;

Answer (score 7):

[WEEKDAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) returns an index from 0 to 6 for Monday to Sunday
[DAYOFWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) returns an index from 1 to 7 for Sunday to Saturday
So, the same day has different indexes, eg. Sunday can be 1 or 6

Often I prefer to use `DAYOFWEEK()` because SQL functions like [ELT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) are 1-index based :

```
SELECT ELT(DAYOFWEEK(NOW()), 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
SELECT ELT(WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 1, 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
```